# Cell need to be highlighted as bold in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have cell values like #2(#3),#4(#3) and so on.. if the value outside the braces is lower than the value inside the braces, then it should highlight as bold.

eg: #2(#3) is the cell value (here #2 < #3) then it should highlight, I need to get a formula or code to do this, as i have a long range of the cell values, Doing manually everytime is a kind of time taking, Anyone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following conditional formatting rule(to Bold):

```
=QUERY(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"#(\d+)\(#(\d+)\)"),"Select true where Col1<Col2 label true ''")
```

Apply to range A1:Z500

**EDIT(BUG FIX)**:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(--REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"#(\d+)\(#(\d+)\)")),"Select true where Col1<Col2 label true ''")
```

There seems to be a rare bug in detecting numbers by `QUERY`. And this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: replying lately, it is not working for all the values even it is fall in the category.As i have taken data for two weeks looking up with a formula, it is not getting bold for few cells.

Comment: @rajup Find the differentiating factor.  Find out why it doesn't work with certain entries. What's different with those entries?

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to find out why it is not taking the formulae for few cells,eg  cell J1 and also i want to bold the cases where eg. #182(#)) but not like      
#(#120), could you please check and help me out. Here is the sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSGCN7xn5oUrkgiU9A38XlTVSdi_wS7uFltyiYPkIew/edit#gid=0

Comment: @rajup, why should #182(#) be highlighted and not like #(#120)?  It's completely against all the previous rules set forth (where inside should be greater than outside? ) Please ask a different question for this

Comment: @rajup, I think I've satisfactorily answered your original question and debugged my solution as well (Check my edit)